# Android Save files on server only

Tags: php, android, server, storage

I'm new to Android and would like to ask is it possible to save the files (incl. image, text etc) created within a app directly to the php server? Without saving it in any internal or external storage like SD card?

This is due to users are not allowed to access to the data once they offline.Users shall not kept anything to their personal device other than accessing it online by login in.

I have read through the passage of Data Storage in Android developer website. What was mentioned there is just the ways for data storage. Web server as the last options without having any examples.

Please advise and give a snippet if possible.

Another questions will be, in such a situation(save in server without saving in SD card). Any idea on how to keep the created data temporary if let's say the internet connection is down? And I do not wish to lost any data?

Please give some suggestion, if you have any for the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can definitely save data to a server and not ever write it to the local disk: Google is your friend and will provide examples such as [this](http://www.androidsnippets.com/executing-a-http-post-request-with-httpclient) if you search for *android POST http*.

Answer (score 1):

No exampele because nothiong is android specific here .

create webservice to store file send the data to webservices from device  . in case of images send its ByteStream . [example is here](http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html) .